# Passing laravel variables to Vue frontend

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

in order to pass php variables from laravel to vue frontend I created a Javascript class, I use this class static put method to send an associative array to frontend.

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;


class Javascript
{

    public static function put($array, $request)
    {
        //I call this static method to pass backend variables to Vue, from blade I json_encode the payload, assign it to a window variable
        //and later add it to the Vue.prototype so I can access in vue components like this.$app.whatever.

        //This helper method can be called more than one time in laravel's request->reponse cycle, from middleware, controller action, route redirect ... 
        //so instead of creating recreating $app array everytime I want to find a way to push passed key value pairs to a global javascript object

        $app = array();

        $app = array_merge($request->globals, $array);

        view()->share('app', $app);
    }

}
```

When I want to return a laravel blade view wth javascript data I do it like this:

```
$featuredPosts = Post::where('isFeatured', true)->where('isVisible',true)->with('postcategory')->get();

Javascript::put([
  'meta' => $meta,
  'featuredPosts' => $featuredPosts,
], $request);

return view('publicaciones.list', compact('meta'));
```

And in my blade master layout:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.$app = {!! json_encode( $app ) !!};</script>
```

Another case is when I want to have global variables for all routes/views, for this purpose I have a global middleware called GlobalsVar where I do.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   $globals['auth'] = Auth::user() ?  User::with('appointment')->find(Auth::id()) : false;

   $globals['previousUrl'] = URL::previous();

   $request->globals = $globals;

   return $next($request);
}
```

Currently inside my Javascript class I create an empy array and merge part of my requests with the passed array from my controllers, I also pass request object as seconda parameter, I want to improve this in two ways:

1) Each time I call Javascript::put static method the passed values are merged into the exisiting object, this is because if during the request -> response cycle I call Javascript::put the payload is recreated and previous data is lost, is there a way to preserve this data?

2) I don't want to pass Request $request object each time I run Javascript::put, is there a way to always inject the Request method

Comment: Why would you do this? just get the data via Ajax

Comment: I agree with Saly - just make this a Vue component, call the PHP endpoint with axios in the Vue component's script and output the result in the component's template. You can persist the data locally with Vuex or/and localStorage

Comment: My app is a non-spa laravel-vue hybrid, basically all my views are blade simple layouts with vue components composing the UI/UX, afaik doing ajax calls after initial render is an antipattern, I mainly use vuex afor my admin panel and dispatching axios calls through my api endpoints after the page is rendered, there's also some data I want in my pages which is not in vuex. is what I'm doing that bad? I add window variables to vue prototype and can access in all components that way so it's really handy for me.

Answer (score 0):

if your call vue from blade you can pass laravel data like props

```
@extends('index')
@section('contenido')
  <div id="content-container">
     <div id="page-head">
     </div>
     <div id="page-content">
        <vue-file :variable="{{ $variable}}"></vue-file>
    </div>
@endsection
```

and in the vue-file you can get it like this

```
props:{
 variable:Array  
}
```